# gatsby-browser.js won't load css file - hello-world tutorial

Tags: gatsby

I"m going through this gatsby docs tutorial on the basics of styling, and the css file isn't being imported or rendered onto the page.

the instructions are:
2. Import your recently-created stylesheet in the gatsby-browser.js file:

```
import "./src/styles/global.css"
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-two/

global.css simply has an html tag:

```
html {

    background-color: red;
}
```

the background color isn't showing however. The web server is running and I am looking at the correct page. (I can add more text in index.js and it shows). The files are saved, as I've tried this a few times. I also tried using "require" as shown in the tutorial but this also did not work.

Also, the console in development tools is telling me:

```
index.js:2177 404 page could not be found. Checkout https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-404-page/
```

I don't know what page its referring to since so far I only have index.js.

Thanks

Comment: Can you see your `background-color` css rule in the developer tools?

Comment: @ksav No, I only see the "user agent stylesheet" with a body tag put in by the browser.

Comment: Is `gatsby develop` still running in your terminal? If you make a simple change to your index page component, is it reflected in the browser?

Comment: @ksav Yeah, i just checked again, adding more text next to "hello world"  it shows.

Answer (score 2):

*It had nothing to do with how you created the files.*
What you needed to do was stop the gatsby develop (server) locally, and start it up again.  I believe the 'gatsby-browser.js' file must be loaded at startup.

Answer (score 1):

OK so since its only a couple of steps, I decided to scrap the project and do it again.

I then realized that the instructions had said to run "touch [filename]" within the terminal to create the files, for both global.css and gatsby-browser.js. I had created them in VS Code I think. Having redone these steps with the touch the command, the background color is showing. I'm not sure why that made a difference within gatsby, but it does apparently. I'm still reading up to find out why.

Comment: Very likely not because you used `touch`... Not even sure if there would be any different with a file created with `touch` vs VS Code. Probably something else was the issue